# php client content uploads (cms)

Tags: php, content-management-system, upload

HI I'm building a php based website and wanted to know if there any way to allow my client to upload their content from a word document (or any word file)?

The upload should replace (or add) content to a page, allowing her to update her content. I know this is some sort of cms, but I don't know where to begin.

I currently have an article.php page that uses this code:

```
<?php

$thisPage="Writing";

include("header.php");


$page = $_GET['article'];
$file = "articles/".$page.".html";
if(file_exists($file)) {
  include($file);
} else {
  print "404 Error. Page does not exist";
}

function IsSafeInclude($x) {
    if(strpos($x, "/../") !== false || strpos($x, "../") === 0 || strpos($x, "/..") == (strlen($x) - 3) || $x == '..')
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

include("html/articles-left.html");

include("footer.php");

?>
```

The $page function allows me to link different html files that would load when clicked. What I want to do is allow the client to upload/update her different articles to the site. Make it easy to use.

Here is the link to the site: [here](http://www.skyviewmarketing.net/clients/Cheryl/index.php)

Thanks alot!

gdinari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking is non-trivial and, by the question you make you probably should start with something easier, like a `textarea` and teach the client how to Copy/Paste text from other documents.

1. start with html simple `textarea`
2. try using [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) to have an improvement while keeping graceful degradation
3. add a file uploader and [read that .DOC file](http://drewd.com/2007/01/25/reading-from-a-word-document-with-com-in-php) and pass it to the text-area

Comment: Frankie, thanks for the advice. I wouldve replied sooner, but Ive been working on some projects...I looked in the tinymce and file uploader solution you suggested, but I have a few questions: (1) Wouldn't I need some sort of login to access the editable area and then save it so no one else can change it and make the content non-editable after save? (2) I read the documentation for install (not hard to implement), but what about implementing the file uploader, how would I do that? Would it have been easier to just build this site from a cms platform, what is the best would you suggest?

Comment: @gdinari you're dealing with two problems. Backoffice vs Frontoffice being the first and how to file upload being the second. In SO style I would suggest you approach them as different things and, after trying, ask here whatever questions you may have.